# How to refresh UISearchBar search results when type without need to press "Search" button? Is there any native way?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I'm working on a very simple app like Notes and I have searchBar. But, every time I want to search, I have to type something in searchBar and press the Search button. Is there a way to search when I type? Typed one character - table refreshed, typed another - table refreshed again.

This is how my extension looks like. loadData() is a function that loads data from CoreData to tobleView.

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text CONTAINS[c] %@", searchBar.text!)

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true)]

    loadData(with: request)
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        getNotes()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    } else {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.endEditing(true)

    getNotes()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transfered code from searchBarSearchButtonClicked() func to searchBar textDidChange() func. 
Now it works and looks like:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
        getNotes()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    } else {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Note> = Note.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text CONTAINS[c] %@", searchBar.text!)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "text", ascending: true)]

        getNotes(with: request)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "getNotes()" is the method you have to query the users saved notes. What you should/could do is add a completion handler to getNotes() and a parameter that takes a string. Using the delegate method textDidChange (which you already conform to) you can do something like this...

```
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    guard let txt = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), !txt.isEmpty else {return}

    getNotes(searchText: txt) { (results) in
        // Set your data source with new results
        self.src = results
        // Reload collection
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reload()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a hook to textDidChange will work but it has some downsides. For example: if the user types too fast, you will be querying the server (if the filtered results are fetched from server) or filtering the array (if the results are local) too many times when those filtering and querying operations are not really important because the user is still typing.

Instead, what you can do is use RxSwift. This is an amazing library and serves a lot of purposes. The idea is to treat the typing of the user as a stream of events. Then using RxSwift, you can apply some logic on that stream of events. For example, how much to wait for the next querying/filtering operation, to have distinct value and many other operations.

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@phenriquelima.ph/search-with-rxswift-c6832e881712) example.

Comment: Regarding your first point of querying the server too many times, OP can circumvent this by search throttling: make a `Timer` object inside `textDidChange()` and wait a set amount of time (e.g. 0.5 seconds), then call `invalidate()` on the timer to reset it.